# XMPP support in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I need a way for my ASP.NET app to communicate with Google's GCM Cloud Connection Server, which uses XMPP. Doing a google search doesn't seem to indicate that .Net has any built-in support for XMPP. There also doesn't appear to be any really well established open source libraries although there are commercial libraries available. Any suggestions on a good library for communicating with GCM CCS?

Comment: Did you find any library or source code for `Cloud Connection Server XMPP implementation` in `.NET`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a XMPP library for .NET.
Goto http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/ and find a XMPP library for .NET which you can integrate in your ASP.NET project.